# What is the best practice for registering a new user in my case?

Tags: python, registration

I am going to let new users register on my service. Here is the way I think it should go:
1. User enters his email in a field and clicks Register button.
2. User receives a confirmation email with a link containing a verification code.
3. User goes by that link from the email message where he sees a message that his account is activated now.

So, the main point I am to figure out how to implement is the second one. How do I better generate that code? Should I generate it when the user clicks Register button and save it in the field, say "verification_code" near the field "email" and then when he goes to the verification link, compare the values? Then, if that's fine, clear the "verification_code" field and set "user_is_active" field to "True". Or may be I don't have to keep that code in the database at all, but make a just in time verification with some algorithm? May be there are other things I should consider?

Comment: the tags algorithms and generatore were a little misleading so i removed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it useful to put a verification code in the database and use it as you've suggested. The same field can do double duty for e.g. password reset requests.

I also use an expiry timeout field, where registrations or password resets need to be dealt with by the user in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a project that does exactly what you want. It's called [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/). I suggest using this project instead of rolling your own.

If you still want to do it yourself, then look at the code for django-registration. It has really good comments and is really a perfect app to learn from.

Comment: I am to use it in Google App Engine and I need something little, simple, without much magic. That's why I am just asking about the logical way doing this, not a complete solution. Then I will be able to apply that logic to create my own light code.